# Есть 2 сайта - основной и для мобильных устройств. Как сделать, чтобы для мобил открывался 2 сайт?

Tags: вёрстка, мобильная-разработка

Создал 2 вышеупомянутых сайта, но нигде не могу найти, как сделать, что если открываешь сайт с телефона, открывается сайт с мобильных устройств, а если с пк, то основной сайт. Возможно киньте ссылку на ресурс, где объясняют?
Я картофан, извините за такой вопрос.

Comment: Нужно настраивать прокси сервер. А вообще в чем необходимость делать отдельный сайт под мобильные устройства?

Answer (score 0):

зачем делать 2 сайта? если можно использовать один с media запросами?

используйте @media (max-width: 992px) для планшетов
и @media (max-width: 576px) для мобильных разрешений
пример кода с медия запросами, также с media можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/)

```css
.goal
  background-color: #f8f8f8
  &-block
    display: flex
    img
      margin: 30px auto
      margin-right: 50px
      max-width: 185px
      width: 100%
      height: 179px
    &__text
      h1
        font-size: 50px
        color: #95e1d3
        font-weight: normal
      p
        +italic
        font-size: 20px
        line-height: 200%
        span
          font-weight: bold
@media (max-width: 992px)
  .goal
    &-block
      p
        font-size: 18px
@media (max-width: 768px)
  .goal
    &-block
      p
        font-size: 16px
@media (max-width: 576px)
  .goal
    &-block
      display: flex
      flex-direction: column
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]